# Asking for a contract extension

Tags: professionalism, communication, contracts

I have a six months contract. Now on the fifth month, I was asked (verbally) by my HR Management head if I want to have another 6 months contract extension because of reasons:

1. I'm a good worker (based on the results of my Productivity Sheets filled up by my manager every month, they said)
2. Instead of looking for another worker to replace me, they want to retain me (considering the learning curve a new employee must take, the familiarity with the project, etc)
3. Other workplace reason (many employees, who are regulars, like me to be around, etc)

But since it is impromptu, (they only passed by my branch office that day to have a meeting to my manager, and since there is few minutes left) they use that to talk to us few contractual about our end-of-contract.

I answered that I would like to sign another contract. After it is settled, we then have a mutual understanding, and they told me that we will meet again having the new contract with them on the later date. The people present on that meeting was me, my site manager, and the HR Management head, **and it is concluded before we separate that I will have a contract extension for another 6 months.**

Now it is my last week, and yet, no conversation ever happened about my contract termintation. Is it polite to *re-* inform them that my contract is ending and I want to sign another contract, after all they commit that they're willing to do so. How should I compose my message? Or should I wait for their call? There seems to be a small ruckus on the main office as of late, and I don't want to bother them as of the moment...

Comment: Asking about something you have agreed on is not a big deal in my opinion. Would anyone care to comment in on this?

Comment: Yes you can ask them politely. There will be no issue in that as everything is decided in previous meeting.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to work there for next 6 months then you should ask to HR because it is last week of your current contract. And there is nothing like mistake about asking them for next 6 months contract because it is already discussed in your last meeting with HR.

It might possible that HR has your letter and agreement ready but because of some busy schedule/work they forgot to meet you again. So feel free to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with asking, and in your situation it's critical to do so as soon as possible since you are on your last contracted week. The best person to ask would be your site Manager, they have a vested interest in making everything go as smoothly as possible.

Explain your concerns politely and the fact that you need to finalise you plans for the next 6 months. Your manager should understand and help you get any information promptly by following up with HR.

All in all I think you have nothing to worry about, but you need to follow up as soon as you can, because whichever way it goes it will affect the next 6 months and you need to prepare.

Reasons why it could be taking so long can vary, most would be innocuous. In my experience the worst that can happen is that it's been left until the last minute because they want to pressure you into signing a contract that if you'd known about the details earlier you may well have looked for another job.

Or that they have changed their minds for some reason.

But that is worst case scenario.

Depending on how proactive the company is in these matters, I would expect that there is nothing to be concerned about in terms of getting the contract.